# Continue the execution after catching the error in try-catch block

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, try-catch, doubly-linked-list

After catching an exception, how do I continue the execution of a Java program?

So I made a program to insert or delete nodes from specific positions in Doubly Linked List. Those 2 methods throw exception.

In main method, I have started to insert some int values to positions. If I entered wrong pos value insert method throws an error and catch block handle.

1. If I have entered 30 nodes and insert them to the correct positions except 1 Node.
   -After false entry (i.e in the middle of the insertions) how can I continue to insert the rest?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        try {
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
            myList.Insert(5, 54); //  this is the false entry
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
        
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        myList.Out();
        myList.ReverseOutput();     

      }

    }
```

```
So after execution, the output is 1. How can I make it [1 , 1 , 1]?
```

Comment: This question is an indication that you are using exceptions for flow control, which is an [anti-pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).  Exceptions are for truly exceptional conditions from which you don't usually want to continue.  If the condition that throws the exception is part of normal operation, then use a different mechanism, such as a special return value.  In your case, your `LinkedList#Insert()` method should return a boolean `true` for successful insert and `false` for "out of order insert".

Comment: Also, it should be `insert()` and not `Insert()`, and your class shouldn't be named the same as the standard library class `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `myList.insert` in a method which ignores the Exception, and use that instead:

```
static void insertAndIgnoreException(LinkedList list, int position, int value) {
  try {
    list.Insert(position, value);
  } catch (LinkedListInsertionException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

So your main becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        insertAndIgnoreException(1, 0);
        insertAndIgnoreException(5, 54); //  this is the false entry
        insertAndIgnoreException(1, 0);
        insertAndIgnoreException(1, 0);

        myList.Out();
        myList.ReverseOutput();     

  }
```

Some notes:

1. I've used a specific exception type `LinkedListInsertionException`. *Never* catch and ignore `Exception`, as you'll end up missing all sort of other problems, e.g. `NullPointerException`s.
2. Stick to Java naming conventions in your code. i.e. `insert` not `Insert`.
3. Don't reuse JDK class names, i.e. use `MyLinkedList` not `LinkedList`.

Comment: Since we have used try-catch in insertAndIgnoreException() method, don't we have to surround statement " insertAndIgnoreException(1, 0)  with try-catch again? Also for the specific exception type LinkedListInsertionException, do I have to define it? Bcs my IDE doesnt find that specific exception type :/

Comment: You will have to create that exception class and throw it from your `Insert` method, instead of whatever exception you are throwing now (or if you already throw a more specific exception, catch that instead of `Exception`). There's no need to use `try/catch` in `main`, no checked exception is thrown by `insertAndIgnoreExceptions`.

Comment: So actually, my Insert method throws an Exception right? Inside the method for the false entries I throw LinkedListException() which is defined in the same class with Exception return type. So now I have public Exception LinkedListException() in the same class. Also I have defined custom exception class which is insertAndIgnoreException. So from Exception LinkedListException(), I return new insert..Exception("False entry") . İn the custom exception class I extends Exception and only used contructor method for the message. Is there any way to change custom class for not halting

Comment: I mean without defining extra method   '**static void insertAndIgnoreException(LinkedList list, int position, int value)**'  . Can we make to continue to program using custom exception class?

Comment: I don't understand what either `public Exception LinkedListException()` means, or why you call `insertAndIgnoreException` a "custom exception class". If a statement in the body of a try/catch throws an exception, all following statements in the block are skipped. There is no way around that.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. In my LinkedList class I have **public Exception LinkedListException()** method. I throw this exception **inside** of the **Insert** method according to the cases, but **Insert** throws Exception. Exception return type method return exception class which is **LinkedListInsertionException** that you have suggested.

Comment: You should either update your question with your new code, or ask a new question if your current question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you can solve this by using a [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Something like:

```
int[] numsToInsert = new int[] {1, 0, 5, 54, 1, 0, 1, 0};

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2){
    try {
        myList.Insert(numsToInsert[i], numsToInsert[i + 1]);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

This will catch the exception separately for each insertion by performing the insertions iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you don't.

... but that doesn't mean there is nothing you can do.

The purpose to a try/catch is stop all processing once an error is detected. Its purpose is to skip the rest of the code (through to the catch). It's doing exactly what it is supposed to do, it is the same as saying "skip me".

So your question "how do I run the rest of the code" can only be acheived by removing the code from "skip me" instruction.

```java
        try {
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
            myList.Insert(5, 54); //  this is the false entry
        
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        myList.Insert(1, 0);
        myList.Insert(1, 0);
        myList.Out();
        myList.ReverseOutput();
```

This will give you the output you expect.

... but it doesn't *feel* quite right

If we are removing code from the `try` it almost seems like the try isn't worth having. The thing is, that try block was put there there for **some** reason. Try blocks are supposed to catch errors and it successfully did so, so obviously its doing something useful, and taking the code out of it feels like the wrong solution.

What we want is for *each one of the lines of code* to be tried, and if it fails, try the next one. Notice I said `try` more than once, and also "each **one**"

```
        try {
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            myList.Insert(5, 54); //  this is the false entry
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            myList.Insert(1, 0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

This will also give you the output you want, and also handles any of those inserts kicking out an error.

... but it doesn't *feel* quite right

That's a lot of repetitive text, just to do the same insert over and over. If only we had a way to repeat things?

```
int values[4][2] = {
    {1,0},
    {5,54},
    {1,0},
    {1,0}
};

for(int v[2] : values){
    try {
        myList.Insert(v[0], v[1]);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

This will give you the output you want, handles any of the inserts kicking out an error, and avoids the constant repetition.

... but it doesn't *feel* quite right

There was no loop being used for that original code. I assume that was for a reason: possibly it was a test stub that will eventually be receiving values from somewhere else.

This indicates that having each item tested independantly is *the actual purpose* of this code. If so, there is a way that we could have the single line of code handle its own error:

```
function TryInsert(list,pos,val){
    try {
        list.Insert(pos, val);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
}

...

TryInsert(mylist, 1, 0);
TryInsert(mylist, 5, 54); //  this is the false entry
TryInsert(mylist, 1, 0);
TryInsert(mylist, 1, 0);
```

This will give you the output you want, handles any of the inserts kicking out an error, and is more true to the original intent.

... but it doesn't *feel* quite right

Given you are passing in the `myList` object to every function call, it seems like that object is the thing to be acted upon. This would indicate that this is the true desired behaviour of your `Insert` function.

Perhaps you would like to alter your class, either to add this function to it, or modify the `Insert` to act on its own best judgement when the error occurs (either directly or through inheritance).

```java
myList.TryInsert(1, 0);
myList.TryInsert(5, 54); //  this is the false entry
myList.TryInsert(1, 0);
myList.TryInsert(1, 0);
```

Given I don't have access to your class ... I leave it as an exercise to the reader.

**refactoring is fun**